# Why my google map v2 not showing the whole world some region just grey?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing location base application.I can get some location and direction between one location and other, but my Google map just showing Europe and America and a half Asia, Australia and Indonesia doesn't shows up, just grey grid.I run this on genymotion.
I don't know what to do. Already searching in Google and I got nothing.

i think my code works fine, but on a certain place the google maps just dont showing up

im sorry im really new in android development
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better to post your code and screenshot of your map view for better information

Comment: im sorry but i need 10 reputation for posting images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some parts of the map are being shown then that means you have implemented the Google map without any issue, the grey part is usually caused because of slow internet connection which causes the device to be delayed in loading the tiles, test it on a Android Device directly and it will be fine. I HOPE :)

Comment: i think my connection is good on my emulator, but ill try it on my android device, thanks..